# Node: Combining Async/Await with Bluebird

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await

Lately I've been using async/await syntax with NodeJs, and I'm loving it. But occasionally, I want to use some of the functionality of libraries like bluebird. In those cases, I'm having issues with execution order. For example:

```
/// *** in util.js:
// return filename if exists, else false
async function fileExists(f) {
  try {
    await fs.statAsync(f);
    return f;
  } catch (e) {
    if (e.code !== 'ENOENT') throw e;
    return false;
  }
}

// *** in index.js
// look for template having multiple possible file extensions
async function getTemplateFile(templateDir, stackName) {
  const f = await Promise.any(_.map(['yml', 'json', 'yaml'], async(ext) =>
    await util.fileExists(`${path.join(templateDir, stackName)}.${ext}`)));
  if (f) return f;
  else throw new Error(`Stack template "${stackName}" not found!`);   
}
```

The above code will always throw the 'not found' exception the first time I run it, but succeed thereafter (something to do with file system data being cached on subsequent executions?).

How can I avoid the seeming race condition here? Should I abandon async/await syntax entirely and just use standard .then / .catch notation if I have to use native bluebird functionality?

Comment: What does `util.fileExists` return?

Comment: @JaromandaX Just added it to the snippet

Comment: how (and when) does that function become `util.fileExists`? perhaps your code is adding that function to `util` only after `getTemplateFile` is called the first time (I'm clutching at straws here)

Comment: oh, wait ... fileExists resolves to false if file doesn't exist - which means the resolved value will be false, and Promise.any will resolve to false, hence why your if (f) is false - really, you only need `return fs.statAsync(f);` in fileExists (I assume statAsync is a promisified fs.stat?)

Comment: hang on, just getting up to speed what Promise.any does, and I think you're using the wrong tool for the job

Comment: I catch the exception so that I can return false if it throws.... you might be right about Promise.any -- my goal was to resolve the Promise if _any_ of them return a truthy value.

Comment: yeah, but Promise.any doesn't care what the resolved value is as far as I can see

Comment: try what I suggested, reading Promise.any docs suggests it should work

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I should just handle exception in caller instead of catching it.